# Angular add babel for spread operator

Tags: javascript, angular, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I have an angular application created using the CLI.  This app contains a JavaScript file of utility methods (utils.js). My Angular components, written in TypeScript, call functions in this JavaScript utility file. A couple of the methods in "utils.js" contain the ES6 spread operator, i.e.

```
return {
   ...myItem
}
```

When I run my app in all browsers, IE and Edge do not render the page and the console shows

```
SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Expected identifier, string or number
```

My browserlist says to include IE11

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 11
```

How do I get angular to transpile the JavaScript code into ES5 code which will run in IE/Edge.

As I understand it the settings in "tsconfig.json" is for TypeScript files, so will not apply to the .js file.

As the application was created using CLI there is no WebPack config file for me to add babel to it for the .js files.

**What I have tried**

*Core-js/regenerator runtime*

I tried adding the following to the top of the 'utils.js' file

```
import 'core-js'; // replacement for babel-polyfill in babel 7.4 & above
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'; // replacement for babel-polyfill in babel 7.4 & above
```

and added the dependencies to package.json and installed them

```
"core-js": "~3.6.5",
"regenerator-runtime": "~0.13.5",
```

This made no difference

*tsconfig.json*

I have tried "es5" and "es2015" for the target but this makes no difference

*polyfills.js*

I have tried importing all of core-js in the polyfills.js file and this made no difference.

I also uncommented "import 'classlist.js';" and installed that library and that made no difference.

**Update**

I have rewritten my utils.json file to not have the spread operator. The app now renders in Edge.

But it still does not render in IE. Further investigation using all 3 of my Angular SSR apps show that these apps are not doing any client side rendering which will be a topic for a different stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd include your polyfills in the `polyfills.ts` file created in the `src` directory by Angular CLI

IE lacks a lot of polyfills to work with Angular. At a minimum, you're going to need:

```
import 'core-js/features/symbol';
import 'core-js/features/object';
import 'core-js/features/function';
import 'core-js/features/parse-int';
import 'core-js/features/parse-float';
import 'core-js/features/number';
import 'core-js/features/math';
import 'core-js/features/string';
import 'core-js/features/date';
import 'core-js/features/array';
import 'core-js/features/regexp';
import 'core-js/features/map';
import 'core-js/features/weak-map';
import 'core-js/features/set';
```

from core-js 3.6.5

Comment: I have tried this previously (i have added this to my original question of what i have tried), i tried adding all of the core-js in the polyfills.ts file and it made no difference.  I also thought you can not polyfill the spread operator, it has to be transpilled not polyfilled.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm almost certain `core-js/features/symbol` has the spread polyfill.